# Rank of Matrix Determined by Square Submatrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, reference-request, matrix-rank

In an answer to this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2762023/proof-rank-of-a-random-arbitrary-size-matrix-is-full-rank-with-probability-1), it is argued that an $n\times m$ matrix $A$ is of full rank $r=\min\{n,m\}$ if and only if every $r\times r$ submatrix $A'$ is invertible.  This seams intuitive but does anyone have a reference for this result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have stated it, this is wrong. Consider the matrix $A=(1 \ 0)$ which has full rank $1$ but the $0$ submatrix is not invertible.

I assume you are referring to jlewk's answer where he uses that an $n\times m$ matrix has full rank $r:=\min(m,n)$ if and only if **there exists** an invertible $r\times r$ submatrix $A'.$
[The rank of a matrix is the same as the rank of its transpose](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2315/is-the-rank-of-a-matrix-the-same-of-its-transpose-if-yes-how-can-i-prove-it) so we may assume that $n\geq m$ by transposing the matrix, if necessary. Then we get this chain of equivalencies: $A$ has rank $r=m$ $\Leftrightarrow$ There exist $m$ linearly independent columns of $A$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $A$ has an invertible $m\times m$ submatrix.