# Let $A$ be a $n\times m$ random matrix with entries from finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$. What is the probability that rank of $A$ is full.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, probability-theory, statistical-inference

Let $A$ be a $n\times m$ random matrix with entries from finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$. What is the probability that rank of $A$ is full.

I know that complex-valued random matrix say $\mathbf{A} \in \mathbb{C}^{M \times N}$ with size $M \times N$ has full-rank, here is the proof

[Proof: Rank of a Random (arbitrary size) Matrix is full rank with probability $1$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2762023/proof-rank-of-a-random-arbitrary-size-matrix-is-full-rank-with-probability-1)

Can some please give me some direction regarding this? Is this result true.

Comment: It is important that you specify the distribution of the matrix. If for instance $A$ is the $0$ matrix with probability $1$, then it's rank is $0$ with probability $1$. Maybe you mean to have the entries drawn i.i.d. from a uniform distribution over the field ?

Comment: Here is the answer for the $n\times n$ case: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1399406/what-is-the-number-of-invertible-n-times-n-matrices-in-operatornamegl-nf. It is not to hard to modify to general $m\times n$.

Comment: @MikeEarnest Thank you very much. How can we modify the result for $n\times m$. Can you please give some hint>

Comment: @P.Quinton You are right. I meant that distribution is uniform. Is the result I am seeking true?

Comment: To modify the result to $n\times m$ you need to ask yourself how many way there is to make $a_i$ not in the span of $\{ a_1,\dots,a_{i-1}\}$ given that they are linearly independent. I recommend you write a fully detail computation as an answer to your question so that people can review it.